# Laravel Passport add a middleware to the default auth/token route

Tags: php, laravel

Am trying to build a multi tennant application and switching between the databases in my middleware

So i have the following middleware

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    //check if request has the value of header
    $passedheader = $request->header('HTTP_X_APP_LOCATION');

    $headers = AppConnectionsModel::get()->pluck('header_val')->toArray();

    if(!isset($passedheader) || !in_array($passedheader,$headers)){
        return response('Invalid Request.', 403);
    }

    //get the actual header passed
    $connection = AppConnectionsModel::where('header_val',$passedheader)->first();
    if($connection){
        Config::set('database.connections.tennant.database', $connection->database);
        Config::set('database.connections.tennant.port', $connection->port);
        Config::set('database.connections.tennant.username', $connection->username);
        Config::set('database.connections.tennant.password', $connection->password);
        Config::set('database.connections.tennant.host', $connection->host);


       return $next($request);

    }else{
        return response("Invalid Request.", 200);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

So what basically the middleware does is to check the connection settings and set to the config

So i would like to apply this middleware to the passport token route that is `oauth/token` so that every time a user sends a request to get a token his or her db is used

In my users model i have

```
protected $connection = "tennant";
protected $table = "tbl_user";
```

How do i override the oauth/token passport route in laravel to use this middleware

As suggested below i have also tried changing middleware priority in kernel file like

```
  protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'appconnection' => \App\Http\Middleware\AppConnectionMiddleware::class,
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'role' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustRole::class,
    'permission' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustPermission::class,
    'ability' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustAbility::class,

];
```

app connection is the middleware io have placed at the top having the handle method shown above But it doesnt get executed before passport oauth/token route

Checking on my configs the passport routes are set in the `AuthServiceProvider` like

```
 class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
  {
  protected $policies = [
      'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
  ];

/**
 * Register any authentication / authorization services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    Passport::routes();
    //
}
```

}

Comment: try changing the priority of middleware, first, your DB connection change middleware should call

Comment: Ive updated the question with middleware priority change in kernel file but this doesnt work.

Comment: @Webinion laravel passport doesnt have middlewares set on the kernel file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add one array in `Kernel.php` file.

```
protected $middlewarePriority = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\AppConnectionMiddleware::class,
    \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials::class
];
```

Please do this and see, it should work.

passport routes

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'appconnection'], function(){ 
    Passport::routes(); 
});
```

Comment: still the middleware is not executed even after setting this, Ive checked and passport routes are added in the AuthServiceProvider

Comment: what do you mean by connection change, Ill share teamviewer with you

Comment: Hi retry connecting

Comment: thanks for your help through teamviewer ive discovered that if i wrap it authservice provider with   Route::group(['middleware'=>'appconnection'], function(){
            Passport::routes();
        });  It now works